# checkbox and its label at the same level

Tags: asp.net, html, css, checkbox

when I create a checkbox with ASP.NET, its label is always at the bottome level of the checkbox. but I want them to be at the same level so that it looks nice. I achieved that as follows;

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chxAgreed" name="chxAgreed" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="chxAgreed">Agreed</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but I do not want to use table inside my markup so much. How can I do the same without table?

Comment: You are using CheckboxList control?

Answer (score 2):

If the question is only about markup (and not ASP, which I have no knowledge of), this is always a good way to do checkboxes:

```
<label for="chxAgreed">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chxAgreed" name="chxAgreed" />
    Agreed
</label>
```

Benefits this has over other markup structures:

- Alignment is easy, practically automatic
- The checkbox and label will be a single clickable area to check/uncheck to input, rather than two separate ones.
- You can actually omit the `for` attribute of the label, and the `id` of the input if desired, it will be implied that the label is for the input it contains.
- You can do some [pretty nice stuff with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/7s4Vk/) using this markup.

The only downside I can think of is that if you want to style the label text (and not the entire label), you'll have to wrap the text in a `<span>`.